# modal would not show up when I put php code in script tag

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a log in feature on my project.
the thing is, at the first time the page is loaded, it will show a modal, then the user must input the username and password to access the page (the same page where the modal is shown.

the modal works perfectly until I put a php code inside the script tag. do you know what should I change to make it works?
here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mymodal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
        });
    });
    $(".redirect").click(function ()
    {
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con, "coba3thesis");

if ($_POST['check'] == "send") {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}

$check = mysqli_query($con, "select * from admin where username='$username'");
$checkrows = mysqli_num_rows($check); //to check username when verifying
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $pass2 = $row['password'];
}

if ($checkrows = 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('SORRY! You are inserting the wrong username or the username were not existed'); location.href='';</script>";
} else {
    if ($pass !== $pass2) {
        echo "<script>alert('SORRY! You are inserting the wrong password, please insert the correct one!'); location.href='';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>location.href='admin%page.html';</script>";
    }
}
?>
    });
</script>
```

in this code:

```
if($_POST['check'] == "send"){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}
```

I use this code in order to get the inserted data (pass and username) by adding a hidden input method (I use this on my other feature), the name of the hidden input is "check" and the value is "send".

The main problems is, the modal would not show after I put the php code. 
Thank you for helping.

here is the updated code:

```
if($checkrows=0){
                echo "SORRY! You are inserting the wrong username or the username were not existed";
                header('Location: admin%page.php');                 
            }else{
                if($pass !== $pass2){
                    echo "SORRY! You are inserting the wrong password, please insert the correct one!";
                    header('Location: admin%page.php');
                }else{
                    header('Location: admin%page.php'); ;
                }
            }
```

Comment: In your php code, in the echos, remove `<script>` tags - open and close ones.

Comment: In echo `<script>` tag might be creating problem, try removing script tag.

Comment: @KarloKokkak still does not work.

Comment: Post the updated code.

Comment: You may wanna enclose all of your js code in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few steps to test out your PHP

1. add these two lines to your code to get PHP feedback.

   `error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors','1');`

These will enable error reports for all php for you.

2. Make sure your connection is correct. It could be giving your site a 500 Error and crashing the page.
3. you dont need to use the script tags inside of your echos because hen the user receives the page, the server will have evaluated and ran all PHP code, and taken it out.